# Questions on Na2Cr2O7 turning to a vapor phase in 2500F furnace. And possible ways, if any, to filter it

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I've looked for answers without success, so turn to the experts. At air temperature, solid-phase sodium dichromate (Na2Cr2O7) -- or the equivalent, sodium dichromate dihydrate (Na2Cr2O72H2O) -- is introduced to a 2500F glass furnace. It can be 5% or more of a ~1200 lb batch comprised largely of silicon dioxide (SiO2). Total time in the furnace = 16 h.

Much of the Na2Cr2O7 goes into solution in glass as a coloring agent. But some portion will off-gas off the glass-melt, transforming into a gas phase.

Question #1: Does the Na2Cr2O7 turn into a liquid first and then reach its boiling point and then evaporate?

Question #2: Or does it turn directly from a solid to a gas -- sublimation? Note that, mixed in the ~1200 lb batch, it goes from air temperature directly into a 2500F furnace.

Either way, gas-phase Na2Cr2O7 vapor particles rise up off the melt.

The furnace exhaust stream is estimated to be greater than 750F.

Question #3: At what temperature will the Na2Cr2O7 vapor particles desublimate -- turn back -- from a gas to solid Particulate Matter?

Question #3.A. Will they return to solid phase prior to reaching the baghouse filters?

Question #4 What size might these vapor particles be? A range in nanometers -- 30 or 50, maybe?

Question #5: Gas phase particles are not captured by normal baghouse filtration, correct?

Question #6. Filters pre-coated with lime are effective at controlling Hydrofluoric acid, for example. (Tons of it are used at this facility.) Is there any filter coating or treatment effective at capturing vapor-phase chromium?

Question #7 Is there any way at all to control vapor-phase Cr off a 2500F glass melt?

I've scoured the literature for many an hour with no luck. Now I'm turning to the experts, starting with you good folks. Many thanks.

Comment: I suspect that the people who are actual experts at this bad-news compound will want to be paid for their efforts.

Comment: Hiya Scott: More that folks with their wallet involved flee from this cluster-bump. Indeed, I've asked a bunch of them. Even ASHRAE, the trade group that sets MERV 1 - 16 filtration standards, said none of their dozens of staffers could spare a moment for questions far easier than the above. In this case, NO publicity is indeed good publicity. Cheers, Dan

Comment: A paid consultant signs an NDA.